# How to create a BigQuery dataset and a table/schema from Java client (without CSV file)

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I think the method starting line 200 [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/samples/java/cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/bigquery/cmdline/BigQuerySample.java) is relevant (edit: I needed to add a parameter to the line
    Insert insertReq = bigquery.jobs().insert(PROJECT_ID, insertJob);
) but it doesn't work. I get "Load configuration must specify at least one source URI"

I have tried the following:

```
    TableSchema schema = new TableSchema();
    List<TableFieldSchema> tableFieldSchema = new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>();
    TableFieldSchema schemaEntry = new TableFieldSchema();
    schemaEntry.setName(myFirstFieldName);
    schemaEntry.setType("STRING");
    tableFieldSchema.add(schemaEntry);
    schema.setFields(tableFieldSchema);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setSchema(schema);
    table.setId(tableName);
    table.setCreationTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    table.setKind("bigquery#table");
    try {
        bigquery.tables().insert(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, table).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

but I get an error `Required parameter is missing`

Comment: What compilation errors are you seeing?

Comment: so the goal is to create a table with 0 rows? what's the use case?

Comment: Yes, I already have code to insert rows, I'm just looking for code to create the empty table. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

OK based on the idea by Jordan Tigani, here is the Java code that works to create a blank table in BigQuery with Google Java API Client:

```
TableSchema schema = new TableSchema();
List<TableFieldSchema> tableFieldSchema = new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>();
TableFieldSchema schemaEntry = new TableFieldSchema();
schemaEntry.setName(myFirstFieldName);
schemaEntry.setType("STRING");
tableFieldSchema.add(schemaEntry);
schema.setFields(tableFieldSchema);

Table table = new Table();
table.setSchema(schema);
TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
tableRef.setDatasetId(DATASET_ID);
tableRef.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
tableRef.setTableId(tableId);
table.setTableReference(tableRef);
try {
    bigquery.tables().insert(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, table).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

To create a dataset (before creating the table)

```
    Dataset dataset = new Dataset();
    DatasetReference datasetRef = new DatasetReference();
    datasetRef.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
    datasetRef.setDatasetId(DATASET_ID);
    dataset.setDatasetReference(datasetRef);
    try {
        bigquery.datasets().insert(PROJECT_ID, dataset).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the project id and the dataset id on the table (I realize that it seems redundant becuase you specify them on the insert() operation, but that is a quirk of REST ... the project and dataset are part of the URL, but they are also part of the resource.

From a raw HTTP api level, the following works:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/datasets/mydataset/tables?alt=json    
{"tableReference": 
    {"tableId": "dfdlkfjx", "projectId": "myproject", "datasetId": "mydataset"},
 "schema": 
     {"fields": [{"name": "a", "type": "STRING"}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks that gave me the clue how to do it in Java, see my answer